# Max function for varchar column containing numbers and characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, max

I used SSMS to create a table:

```
create table test_max_func(
             seq_no int,
             content varchar(255)
);
```

Then I inserted some rows into it:

```
insert into test_max_func(seq_no, content)
values (1, '2.4l multiair i-4 engine'),
       (1, '2.6l multiair i-4 engine'),
       (1, '2.4l engine'),
       (1, '2.6l engine');
```

And I get a table like this:

```
     seq_no     content
------------------------------------------
        1       2.4l multiair i-4 engine
        1       2.6l multiair i-4 engine
        1       2.4l engine
        1       2.6l engine
```

Then I execute the following SQL commands:

```
select seq_no, max(content) from test_max_func
group by seq_no
```

And I get:

```
seq_no  (No column name)
---------------------------
   1    2.6l multiair i-4 engine
```

Can you explain why `2.6l multiair i-4 engine` is the max one in content column?

Comment: What result do you actually expect?

Comment: According to the alphabetical order.

Comment: Because sorted alphabetically that is the one closest to end of the sorting chain. Using MAX on a character field like that is a bit odd.

Comment: I don't have a specific expected result. I'm just wondering how SQL works implicitly to get such a result.

Comment: The same way as it works for `SELECT TOP 1 content FROM test_max_func ORDER BY content DESC`

Answer (score 2):

Since your column is of a string datatype, the database performs string-wise comparison. That is, compare characters one by one in both strings, going left to right: as soon as a character is greater than its counterpart, the comparison stops. Basically this is alphabetical comparison, similar to how names are sorted in a phone book.

For your dataset, let's search for the maximum value:

```
2.4l multiair i-4 engine
2.6l multiair i-4 engine
2.4l engine
2.6l engine
```

The first two characters (`'2.'`)are identical in all strings. Then, `'6'` is greater than `4`, so we are left with two values:

```
2.6l multiair i-4 engine
2.6l engine
```

These strings first differ at character 6, where `'m'` is greater than `'e'`, so the maximum value is `2.6l multiair i-4 engine`.

Comment: So here 6 is greater than 4 b/c six's s is greater than four's f alphabetically? Am I right?

Comment: @VivHuang this is determined by the [`collation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15) which for many collations uses the ANSI value of the character.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you were to order the `content` column alphabetically, it would be last in the list (at least for collations that I'm most familiar with).  Hence, `max()` returns that value because it is the "biggest" value for the column.

This seems rather obvious.  Perhaps you should explain your confusion?

Comment: What I think SQL would do is: first convert all rows into character, for example: 2.4 to two point four, then alphabetically order that column? Am I right?

Comment: 2.4 -- two point four, 2.6 -- two point six, and b/c s is after f, 2.6 is after 2.4, which means 2.6 is greater than 2.4?

Comment: @VivHuang . . . The *column* is already characters because it is a string.  No conversion is involved, just ordering.  They are compared character by character, just like "aardvark" and "zygote" would be (although that comparison only needs the first letter).  The numbers are just examples of *characters* in the string.

Comment: So in this case, can I say it is a comparison among 'two point four l multiair i-4 engine', 'two point six l multiair i-4 engine', 'two point four l engine' and 'two point six l engine'. And b/c s is after f, 2.6 is after 2.4, which means 2.6 is greater than 2.4 and m is after e, then 'two point six l multiair i-4 engine', which is '2.6l multiair i-4 engine' is the largest among them?

Comment: @VivHuang . . . Well, sort of.  There is no "two point four" in the strings.  It is "2.4".  But I think you have the idea.